# datetimepicker validation start date should be less than enddate in the calendar while clicking jquery

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

How do I make start date less than end date in the calendar on datetimepicker? While clicking on end date I should not be able to select the date before start date I selected.

```
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
        startDate = $( "#startDate" )
            .datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 3,
                timepicker: false,
            })
            .on( "change", function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                endDate.datetimepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
            }),
        endDate = $( "#endDate" ).datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            timepicker: false,
        })
            .on( "change", function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                startDate.datetimepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
            });


    function getDate( element ) {
        var date;
        try {
            date = $.datetimepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
        } catch( error ) {
            date = null;
        }
        return date;
    }


});
```

Comment: Have you looked at the date range example in here: [https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)?

Comment: Yes, but it’s for datepicker and I tried the same implementation for datetimepicker but I’m unable to see calendar when I do that

Comment: jQuery UI doesn't have a datetimepicker, you must be using a 3rd party library. Is it this one: [https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker)?

Comment: This is what i used .https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to know which library you're using. See the "Official Website" in your link, it points to this repository: https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker

Then, you can find their document in here: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Look for how they set options by search for this: `setOptions`

```
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
    startDate = $("#startDate")
        .datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            timepicker: false,
            onChangeDateTime: function(currentDateTime ){
                endDate.datetimepicker("setOptions", { "minDate": currentDateTime });
            },
        }),
    endDate = $("#endDate").datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        timepicker: false,
        onChangeDateTime: function(currentDateTime ){
            startDate.datetimepicker("setOptions", { "maxDate": currentDateTime });
        },
    });
```

I suggest you find another library that support this range picker feature by default, that's easier.

On their document site, you can see they have one call `PeriodPicker`, but it's not free. I'll look for something else, there's must be plenty of options.

If you don't need to pick time, just date, then I suggest the jQuery UI's datepicker.

Comment: Thank you... there was a range between date# in the link you provided and it worked well for me. Thank you!